# Iam getting this error how to solve AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setInput'?

Tags: python

I have imported a picture and everything is fine but I am getting an `AttributeError` when running `net.setInput(blob)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

#load the image
img=cv2.imread(r"E:\Face recognition\3_FaceDetection_FeatureExtraction\images\faces.jpg")

cv2.imshow('faces',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(img)
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("E:/Face recognition/Models/deploy.prototxt.txt"),("E:/Face recognition/Models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel")

#extract blob
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1, (300,300), (104,177,123), swapRB=False)
net.setInput(blob)
```

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 net.setInput(blob)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setInput'
```

Comment: Why is there a comma after the call to `readNetFromCaffe`, followed by a string in parentheses?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. you can and should debug your issue before asking.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%c5%a1ek) mentioned in his comment, the critical line is

```py
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("E:/Face recognition/Models/deploy.prototxt.txt"),("E:/Face recognition/Models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel")
```

The comma makes `net` a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) containing the return value of the function calll `cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("E:/Face recognition/Models/deploy.prototxt.txt")` and the string `"E:/Face recognition/Models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel"`.  This is equivalent to

```py
>>> a = 4, "abc"
>>> a
(4, 'abc')
>>> type(a)
tuple
```

In the last line you call `net.setInput(blob)` but a tuple has not attribute or method `setInput`, which is why you get the error.

Probably, you wanted to write `net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("E:/Face recognition/Models/deploy.prototxt.txt", "E:/Face recognition/Models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel")` or simply `net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("E:/Face recognition/Models/deploy.prototxt.txt")` (I do not know the method `readNetFromCaffe`, so I do not know what it requires as input).